# How to prevent from page load to clear my dynamic added textboxes

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a very annoying issue and some help will be very appreciate.
i am creating dynamically text boxes, and with a button i want to create another text box and to save the text which inserted to the last text box.
The thing is when the handler event for the button is called, the page load is called before, and re-creates the page again.
then i lose the dynamic text-boxes i created.
I even tried to save the text-boxes or theirs id in a session but the problem i cant get the text in the last text box because the page load called before.

What can i do in order to save my text before the page load, or can i cancel the page load from creating my page again?

I added my code here:

```
int i = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["orderList"] = null;
        }
    }

    public void create()
    {
            List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>)Session["orderList"];    // get the order list
            TextBox1.Text = orderList[0].Number_Of_Items.ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = orderList[0].PricePerItem;

            for (i = 1; i < orderList.Count; i++)
            {
                Label lb = new Label();
                lb.ID = "lb" + i.ToString();
                lb.Text = "item" + (i + 1).ToString() + ":";
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);

                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "ddl" + i.ToString();
                ListItem li = new ListItem();
                li.Text = "12345";
                li.Value ="5";
                ddl.Items.Add(li);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(ddl);

                Label lb2 = new Label();
                lb2.ID = "lb2" + i.ToString();
                lb2.Text = "Amount:";
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lb2);

                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
                tb.Width = 110;
                tb.Text = orderList[i].Number_Of_Items.ToString();
                Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

                Label lb3 = new Label();
                lb3.ID = "lb3" + i.ToString();
                lb3.Text = "Price Per Item:";
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lb3);

                TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
                tb1.ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
                tb1.Width = 110;
                tb1.Text = orderList[i].PricePerItem;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(tb1);

                Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><br>"));
            }

            // Adding another empty order 

            Label lbLast = new Label();
            lbLast.ID = "lbLast";
            lbLast.Text = "item" + (i + 1).ToString() + ":";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lbLast);

            DropDownList ddlLast = new DropDownList();
            ddlLast.ID = "ddlLast";
            ListItem liLast = new ListItem();
            liLast.Text = "12345";
            liLast.Value = "5";
            ddlLast.Items.Add(liLast);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(ddlLast);

            Label lbLast1 = new Label();
            lbLast1.ID = "lbLast1";
            lbLast1.Text = "Amount:";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lbLast1);

            TextBox tbLast = new TextBox();
            tbLast.ID = "tbLast" + (i + 1).ToString();
            tbLast.Width = 110;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tbLast);

            Label lbLast2 = new Label();
            lbLast2.ID = "lbLast2";
            lbLast2.Text = "Price Per Item:";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lbLast2);

            TextBox tbLast1 = new TextBox();
            tbLast1.ID = "tbLast1";
            tbLast1.Width = 110;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tbLast1);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Order> list = new List<Order>();
        Order order = new Order();

        if (Session["orderList"] == null)      // takes data from .aspx
        {
            order.Number_Of_Items = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            order.PricePerItem = TextBox2.Text;

            list.Add(order);
            Session["orderList"] = list;
            List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>)Session["orderList"];
            create();
        }
        else    // takes data from last order
        {

            list = (List<Order>)Session["orderList"];
            order.Number_Of_Items = list.Last().Number_Of_Items;
            order.PricePerItem = list.Last().PricePerItem;
            list.Add(order);
            Session["orderList"] = list;
            create();
        }
    }


<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Item1:"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">BBB</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Amount:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Price Per Item:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br />
```

**strong text**

Comment: I don't see the problem with `Page_Load` because it's nearly empty. But i see a different problem. You need to recreate dynamic controls in `Page_Load` (at the latest) with the same ID as before. The only thing you need to store is the count of already created controls. From this count you can use a loop to create dynamic ID's which are derived from the index. For example: `"TxtOrder_" + index`

Comment: on page_load call method create() again it will solve your problem..

Comment: the problem is when i'm trying to save the id of the dynamically created text-box the text wont save

Comment: @TimSchmelter that could be an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create(); should be called on every postback. That will recreate all the dynamically created controls and also maintain the values on it.

Here is the code that will do what you are trying to do.

```
    int i = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["Orders"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            create();
        }
    }

   public void create()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < (int)Session["Orders"]; i++)
        {
            Label lb = new Label();
            lb.ID = "lb" + i.ToString();
            lb.Text = "item" + (i + 1).ToString() + ":";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);

            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.ID = "ddl" + i.ToString();
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Text = "12345";
            li.Value = "5";
            ddl.Items.Add(li);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(ddl);

            Label lb2 = new Label();
            lb2.ID = "lb2" + i.ToString();
            lb2.Text = "Amount:";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lb2);

            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
            tb.Width = 110;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

            Label lb3 = new Label();
            lb3.ID = "lb3" + i.ToString();
            lb3.Text = "Price Per Item:";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lb3);

            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.ID = "tb1" + i.ToString();
            tb1.Width = 110;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tb1);

            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><br>"));
        }

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Session["Orders"] = (int)Session["Orders"] + 1;
    }
```